# I can't get JMS example work with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jms

I'm using Eclipse and when I try to build the JMS example included in j2ee tutorial, it return a NullPointerException at this: `connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();` (I used the annotation `@Resource(lookup = "jms/ConnectionFactory")`, if I use jndi, it works fine). This example worked with in Netbeans. Can anyone help me to get it work with Eclipse?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English :(